# Magento URL rewrite issue - redirecting to homepage on my PC

Tags: magento

I did a URL rewrite in Magento. However, the URL is now redirecting to my company's homepage from the category page I did the rewrite on, but it redirects properly for others in my office and some other people I asked to test it. I had the URL rewrite checked by default and it shows up in URL rewrite management. This is confusing and really annoying so any insights would be helpful. :/ :D

Comment: Did you rule anything out? Sounds like you need a hard refresh if other people are loading the change properly.

Comment: We also use Varnish, I'm wondering if that's a cause. I'm seeing this problem from home as well.